# mysql query rollback on query execution error in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am executing a set of mysql query using odbc module. I need to take care of rollback and commit. so at connection time I set {auto_commit, off}. for successful query execution it is working fine. But on error for any query I am unable to rollback or repeat the operation.

When there is an error on query execution the connection got closed. with that dead connection I am not able to do anything. And odbc:commit() works on same connection.

I am not able to repeat the same query with a new connection because mysql locked those records.

How do I Rollback and handle this situation?

Comment: You should try to find out *why* the connection got closed. Is it defined behavior or do you have something in your code which made it close on failure? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: odbc create a process to hold the mysql connection (tcp connection).
when there is any query execution error the odbc reference process receive tcp_closed message, it catch the message in handle info. 
Is the connection getting closed from erlang odbc native driver or mysql?
And How do I Rollback those actions performed before the error?